# MySql backup with date in flename using php

Tags: php, mysql, date, database-backups

my provider told me to use this script to create a Mysql backup:

```
<?php
$host= 'xxx';
$user= 'xxx';
$pass= 'xxx';
$db= 'xxx';

system(sprintf(
'mysqldump --no-tablespaces --opt -h%s -u%s -p"%s" %s | gzip > %s/dumpDB.sql.gz',
$host,
$user,
$pass,
$db,
getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT')
));
echo '+DONE';
?>
```

it works called by a cronjob.
I want to add the date to file name, so I can get more than one file. Something that creates files like “20170216-dumpDB.sql.gz”

How to?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So create it like this

```
$file = date('Ymd') . '-dumpDB.sql.gz';
system(sprintf(
'mysqldump --no-tablespaces --opt -h%s -u%s -p"%s" %s | gzip > %s/%s',
$host,
$user,
$pass,
$db,
getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT'),
$file
));
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work... it just appends the date to the filename.

```
system(sprintf(
    'mysqldump --no-tablespaces --opt -h%s -u%s -p"%s" %s | gzip > %s/%s-dumpDB.sql.gz',
    $host,
    $user,
    $pass,
    $db,
    getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT'),
    date("Ymd")
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date('Ymd')` output: `20170216`

```
$file = date('Ymd') . '-dumpDB.sql.gz'; //20170216-dumpDB.sql.gz
system(sprintf(
'mysqldump --no-tablespaces --opt -h%s -u%s -p"%s" %s | gzip > %s/%s',
$host,
$user,
$pass,
$db,
getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT'),
$file
));
```